# She has felt tried every day

Tags: american-english

A. J. Hoge wrote:

> She has felt tried every day.

Is the word "tried" a typographical error?

Would it be correct if the sentence read:

> She has felt tired every day.

Comment: It is a typographical error. The author meant to write _tired,_ as you thought.

Comment: Please supply the context of the sentence. Then we can determine if it's a typo or deliberate.

Comment: Since starting 10 years ago, Eve has felt bad. She has felt tried every day. She has
had no energy. This started 10 years ago. Before 10 years ago she felt great, but
since 10 years ago…you know until now, until recently…she has felt very tried. She
has not had energy. She hasn’t had energy.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the context you added in the comment above with the repeated mention of "no energy" tells us that *tired* is almost certainly right, I'll take this opportunity to note that the example sentence on its own would still make sense with *tried*. :)

To *try* someone can mean to submit them to trials, ordeals, tests; in short, to put stress on them.

> Oxford English Dictionary: *try*, v.
>   
> 10. To subject to a severe test or strain; to strain the endurance or patience of, put to straits, afflict.
>   
> → 1825   Baroness Bunsen in A. J. C. Hare *Life & Lett. Baroness Bunsen* (1879) I. vii. 248   She has been **tried** in life more hardly than anybody whose..history I ever yet heard.

A modern-day example is the song title "Tried and Tested" by Bruce Cockburn ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4-N1ftnnHs)). Although that phrase usually describes something that's been proven to work through clinical trial, the lyrics of this song pun on the older sense "afflicted, submitted to trials" (by each of the things named).

Similarly, one can find one's experiences *trying* "hard to put up with".

> — "How was work today?"
>   
> — "Extremely trying."

Of course, *tiring* would also fit there, too!

Comment: Luke, I was listening again to A. J. Hoge and I switch on mic on Google Translator, and ultimately, it is type feller.

Comment: @b2ok Good to know. Edited to say that this is just a hypothetical scenario.